# Drawbacks of setting MySQL @@session.time_zone per query instead of CONVERT_TZ?

Tags: mysql

We are storing MySQL timestamp columns in our database.

We are serving multiple web customers in multiple timezones, we often have to query the data sensitive to their timezone to allow them to use their local times.

Here is an example of an average query in our system:

```
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE CONVERT_TZ(created_at, @@session.time_zone, 'America/Denver')
BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59' <--- These are local denver times provided from the customer so we have to convert from the server timezone.
```

As you can see, our current solution is to leverage the `CONVERT_TZ` function to convert from the MySQL server timezone interpretation of the timestamp column into the client's local timezone.

This repetition becomes burdensome on developers and can accidentally be left out of crucial queries. We can often have five or six or more instances of `CONVERT_TZ` in a single query.

To solve this problem we are thinking about leveraging the fact that timestamps are converted automatically by MySQL to the connection `time_zone` variable as outlined here: [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:~:text=MySQL%20converts%20TIMESTAMP,Zone%20Support%E2%80%9D](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20converts%20TIMESTAMP,Zone%20Support%E2%80%9D).

In theory, setting the MySQL `time_zone` to our customer's timezone prior to the query would automatically make all of their queries able to their local timezone without additional conversions.

This idea yields the following query:

```
SET @@session.time_zone = 'America/Denver';
SELECT * FROM user
WHERE created_at <-- No longer have to convert the column, because the MySQL time_zone takes affect.
BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
SET @@session.time_zone = 'SYSTEM'; <-- Revert back to system.
```

Are there drawbacks to this approach? Can multiple queries across sessions/connections be impacted by the variables of another? Are there race conditions between multiple queries that might inherit the incorrect variable before completing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session variables never "leak" into other sessions. Session variables cannot change while the query is running.

The biggest drawback is that you still have datetime values stored in different timezones. You can change the session timezone so you can search based on a given user's preference, but there are many cases when this makes things hard. Here are a few examples, but there may be many others:

- Check which of two users was created first
- Sort a set of rows by datetime
- Allow one user to query the datetime of another user
- Check if multiple users can attend the same meeting

And so on. If you store each user's datetimes according the respective user's preference, then you still need to convert one or the other if you want to compare datetimes.

Another downside of storing datetimes in a user's preferred timezone is what if that user moves to another timezone, and they change their preference? You'd have to update all rows that contain times referenced by that user.

The preferred solution is: **store all datetimes in UTC.**

(Actually, it doesn't matter which TZ you choose, as long as you are consistent. UTC is just a good neutral choice.)

Then you can compare datetimes, you can sort them, and you don't have to worry about developers forgetting how to convert them properly. Convert the values to UTC on insert, and convert them to the user's *current* preference when you display query results.

Comment: Thanks for your response, we just have one clarification to make: in the modern world of connection pooling/persistence is there a threat that two separate requests can be sharing/mutating the same session variables? We are afraid that if two requests hit our application at the same moment, the application will re-use the connection/session and the two queries will affect each other because of them both attempting to set `@@session.time_zone`. Is this a real fear or does connection pooling/persistence preclude session variable sharing?

Comment: Connection pools should reset any state (session variables, user-defined variables, temporary tables, connection character set, etc.) before allocating a connection to a client request. It would be very bad if it leaked any state information through to a different client, because that would violate data privacy. E.g. you would be able to see the data contained in a temporary table belonging to someone else's session. Connection pools that are implemented properly do protect against this. Just use something professional quality and not written by an amateur programmer, and you will be okay.

Comment: Our further testing confirms your statement. Looks like we will be moving forward with this approach. A connection is not released back to our app while still being used by code which means the session is not at risk of being modified by any other queries. A different connection would be made instead.

Comment: Yes, it would be a liability if it _didn't_ work that way.